# Batch assign array value to variable

Tags: arrays, batch-file, variables, assign

I have this code:

```
@echo off
SET /a counter=0
SET _inputname=
Set interfejs=ala
FOR /f "skip=3 tokens=*" %%a in ('netsh int ip show interfaces') do ( call :myfunct "%%a" )

SET /P _inputname=interface: 
IF "%_inputname%" LEQ "%counter%" IF "%_inputname%" GTR "0" (
echo variable value:%_inputname%
call echo [%_inputname%] %%NetInterfNames[%_inputname%]%%

rem problem with assigning array value to a variable.

Set interfejs=%%NetInterfNames[%_inputname%]%%
echo to jest wybrany interface: %interfejs%

Rem split string
rem for /F "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("hello how are you") do echo %%b

)   
IF "%_inputname%" GTR "%counter%" ( GOTO :EOF )
IF "%_inputname%" EQU "0" ( GOTO :EOF )

    goto: EOF

:myfunct
set /a counter=%counter%+1
set NetInterfNames[%counter%]=%~1
call echo [%counter%] %%NetInterfNames[%counter%]%%
```

Inside I'm trying to assign a value taken from array to variable using this

*Set interfejs=%%NetInterfNames[%_inputname%]%%*

Problem is that value form array is not assigned.
Does anyone have an idea of what to do with it?

Comment: Firstly. When using `leq` `gtr` etc. it is better to not enclose the variables in double quotes. i.e `if %var% leq 10 …` Secondly, the correct method to do addition is `set /a counter+=1` Lastly, What is the exact expected output? It is difficult to guess what you require to be the outcome.

Comment: As you're trying to do this without enabling and using delayed expansion, you should be invoking the expansion via a call when `set`ting `interferjs`, i.e. `Call Set "interfejs=%%NetInterfNames[%_inputname%]%%"`. You've used `call` only when `echo`ing, but seemingly forgotten, to do so to `set` the variable value itself.

Comment: This code returns a list of all network interfaces in windows. So after choosing one, I would like to assign it to a variable so then I could use it later

Comment: I test it Call Set "interfejs=%%NetInterfNames[%_inputname%]%%" and it doesnt work.

Comment: Just use `enabledelayedexpansion` instead

Comment: Update your code to its current state, by clicking on the **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58339979/edit)** button at the foot of your question. Include with it, a proper description of what is happening, including any output and your full explanation of what the task is, what the written code is supposed to do, and what exactly you want us to help you with.

Answer (score 1):

And here it is without enabling delayed expansion, to show you that you needed to use an additional `Call`, as per my commented advice. *(I've added a `Pause` to allow you to see any output)*:

```
@Echo Off
Set "counter=0"
Set "_inputname="
Set "interfejs=ala"
For /F "Skip=3 Tokens=*" %%A In ('NetSh int ip show interfaces') Do Call :myfunct "%%A"

Set /P "_inputname=interface: "
If "%_inputname%" LEq "%counter%" If "%_inputname%" Gtr "0" (
    Echo variable value:%_inputname%
    Call Echo [%_inputname%] %%NetInterfNames[%_inputname%]%%

    Rem no problem with assigning array value to a variable.

    Call Set "interfejs=%%NetInterfNames[%_inputname%]%%"
    Call Echo to jest wybrany interface: %%interfejs%%

    Rem split string
    Rem For /F "Tokens=1*" %%A In ("hello how are you") Do Echo %%B

)
If "%_inputname%" Gtr "%counter%" GoTo :EOF
If "%_inputname%" Equ "0" GoTo :EOF

Pause&GoTo :EOF

:myfunct
Set /A counter+=1
Set "NetInterfNames[%counter%]=%~1"
Call Echo [%counter%] %%NetInterfNames[%counter%]%%
```

However if you move two of your `If` commands, you can completely negate the need for one of the code blocks:

```
@Echo Off
Set "interfejs=ala"

Set "counter=0"
For /F "Skip=3 Tokens=*" %%A In ('NetSh int ip show interfaces') Do Call :myfunct "%%A"

Set "_inputname="
Set /P "_inputname=interface: "
If Not Defined _inputname GoTo :EOF
If "%_inputname%" Gtr "%counter%" GoTo :EOF
If "%_inputname%" Equ "0" GoTo :EOF
Echo variable value:%_inputname%
Call Echo [%_inputname%] %%NetInterfNames[%_inputname%]%%
Call Set "interfejs=%%NetInterfNames[%_inputname%]%%"
Echo to jest wybrany interface: %interfejs%

Rem split string
Rem For /F "Tokens=1*" %%A In ("hello how are you") Do Echo %%B

Pause&GoTo :EOF

:myfunct
Set /A counter+=1
Set "NetInterfNames[%counter%]=%~1"
Call Echo [%counter%] %%NetInterfNames[%counter%]%%
```

You could probably improve things a little too, still without enabling delayed expansion:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set NetInterfNames[ 2^>NUL')Do Set "%%A="
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In (
    'NetSh int ip show interfaces 2^>NUL^|Findstr "[0-9]"^|FindStr /N "^"'
)Do Set "NetInterfNames[%%A]=%%B"&Call Echo [%%A] %%NetInterfNames[%%A]%%
:Input
Set /P "_inputname=interface: "
If Not Defined NetInterfNames[%_inputname%] GoTo Input
Call Set "_interfejs=%%NetInterfNames[%_inputname%]%%"
Echo to jest wybrany interface: %_interfejs%

Rem split string
Rem For /F "Tokens=1*" %%A In ("hello how are you") Do Echo %%B

Pause&GoTo :EOF
```

Or with delayed expansion:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set NetInterfNames[ 2^>NUL')Do Set "%%A="
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In (
    'NetSh int ip show interfaces 2^>NUL^|Findstr "[0-9]"^|FindStr /N "^"'
)Do Set "NetInterfNames[%%A]=%%B"&Echo [%%A] !NetInterfNames[%%A]!
:Input
Set /P "_inputname=interface: "
If Not Defined NetInterfNames[%_inputname%] GoTo Input
Set "_interfejs=!NetInterfNames[%_inputname%]!"
Echo to jest wybrany interface: %_interfejs%

Rem split string
Rem For /F "Tokens=1*" %%A In ("hello how are you") Do Echo %%B

Pause&GoTo :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `enabledelayedexpansion` it will help you achieve this much easier.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET /a counter=0
SET _inputname=
Set interfejs=ala
FOR /f "skip=3 tokens=*" %%a in ('netsh int ip show interfaces') do call :myfunct "%%~a"

SET /P _inputname=interface: 
IF %_inputname% LEQ %counter% IF %_inputname% GTR 0 (
echo variable value:%_inputname%
echo [%_inputname%] !NetInterfNames[%_inputname%]!

Set interfejs=!NetInterfNames[%_inputname%]!
echo to jest wybrany interface: !interfejs!

)   
IF %_inputname% GTR %counter% GOTO :EOF
IF %_inputname% EQU 0 GOTO :EOF

    goto :eof

:myfunct
set /a counter+1
set NetInterfNames[%counter%]=%~1
call echo [%counter%] !NetInterfNames[%counter%]!
```